# View is not refreshing and showing up in "Views" SQL server when it's created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create Views in SQL Server for my portfolio. The codes seem to be correct, and when I re-execute the code chunk I get the message "There is already an object named "PercentPopulationVaccinated" in the database", so I'm sure it's somewhere, but when I refresh the views, it's not showing up.
The code I'm using:

```
CREATE VIEW PercentPopulationVaccinated
AS
    SELECT dea.continent,
           dea.location,
           dea.date,
           dea.population,
           vac.new_vaccinations,
           SUM(CONVERT(int, vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.Location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.Date) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
    FROM Portfolio_project..CovidDeaths dea
         JOIN Portfolio_project..CovidVaccinations vac ON dea.location = vac.location
                                                      AND dea.date = vac.date
    WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL;
```

When I check the table with:

```
select *
from PercentPopulationVaccinated
```

the table appears in the pane, so I'm guessing my codes are OK, but just not sure why it's not showing up in the views.

Comment: Presumably you created the object in the wrong database, and you are looking for it in the database you *think* you created it in (which, from your SQL, isn't `Portfolio_project` either).

Comment: Always make sure you add `USE DatabaseNameYouExpectToBeIn;` commands in a separate batch _before_ your `CREATE VIEW` statement. Also always use the schema prefix (e.g. `CREATE VIEW dbo.PercentPopulationVaccinated` and `Portfolio_project.dbo.CovidDeaths` and `select * from dbo.PercentPopulationVaccinated`) since sometimes it can be that you create that object in your own schema, so you're looking in Object Explorer for `dbo.viewname` but it's actually sorted somewhere else in the list.

Comment: Additionally, if you create the views in the same database as the tables, doesn't that make more sense? If you do that then you don't need `Portfolio_project` database prefixes all over the query if the view is already in `Portfolio_project`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  thanks so much for the USE advice...I did that and now it works.  Question if you don't mind-- (this is only the second time I've used sql server so I'm in a learning curve!)  How do I make sure I'm working in the same database as the tables?  I was assuming I was still in the same one when I came back into the project after I had exited a couple days prior.

Comment: When you say "project" I guess it means you're using some flavor of Visual Studio, if that's the case, sorry, I have no idea. Haven't used full-on Visual Studio in probably a decade, and Visual Studio Code only a few times for PowerShell-related stuff.